# Getting excess characters with fread() in C

Tags: c, visual-studio

Okay, so I have tried to read a whole file with fread(), and I can do it successfully, but the longer the file, the more the excess characters I get on the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>



int main() {

    FILE* fpointer = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    char* wholeFile;

    long int fileSize;


    if (fpointer == NULL) return 0;

    fseek(fpointer, 0, SEEK_END); 
    fileSize = ftell(fpointer);
    rewind(fpointer);

    printf("fileSize == %ld\n", fileSize);


    wholeFile = (char*)malloc(fileSize+1, sizeof(char));

    if (wholeFile == NULL) return 1;

    fread(wholeFile, sizeof(char), fileSize, fpointer);
    fclose(fpointer);

    wholeFile[fileSize] = '\0';

    printf("This is whole file:\n\n%s", wholeFile);


    free(wholeFile);
    return 0;
}
```

If the file looks like this:

This is cool file.

I get this as output:

This is cool file.²²²²

And if the file is like this:

This

is

cool

file.

I get this as the output:

This

is

cool
file.═══²²²²

Any idea where I'm wrong?

EDIT: Edited code according to comments.

Comment: Your `malloc` call is strange, can you compile this?

Comment: Yeah, it runs normally, what exactly is strange about it?

Comment: malloc [receives one argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), normally something like `wholeFile = (char*)malloc(fileSize * sizeof(char));`, (well the cast and the `sizeof(char)` are really unnecessary) it's new to me a malloc function that receives 2 arguments.

Comment: Oh, I think it has the same function, it's just written differently.

Comment: You ignore the return value of `fread`, so you have no idea how many characters the translation of the file produced. Similarly, you are only willing to read the number of bytes the file takes in disk form, so if translation to the form your program expects lengthens the file, you won't read the whole file. Line endings can vary in the number of bytes they take up between disk form and the form your program expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate one more than the size of the file and set the last position in the buffer to 0.

C expects character arrays to be null terminated.

Use "rb" to open the file in binary mode. This will ensure you get a reliable count of bytes in the file from Windows.

```
FILE* fpointer = fopen("test.txt", "rb");

wholeFile = (char*)malloc(fileSize + 1);
wholeFile[fileSize] = '\0';
```

Comment: you mean `wholeFile[-1] == '0';` ?

Comment: wholeFile[fileSize] = '\0'

Comment: Okay, it works in the first case, but in the second one I still get excess characters.

Comment: Sure, here it is.

Comment: Change the line FILE* fpointer = fopen("test.txt", "r"); to FILE* fpointer = fopen("test.txt", "rb");.  Windows will then report the correct length of the file in bytes.

Comment: It works! Can you explain to me the difference between "r" and "rb"?

Comment: You are making the assumption that the number of bytes you will read from the file is equal to the size of the file on disk. This is not correct for text files because end-of-line markers may differ in size between what's stored on disk and what your program expects.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you a lot!